# Is this exercise right, or something is wrong or missing.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

I have to find the following limit

For each positive integer $n$ define:

$$a_n = \frac{1}{n}\left[\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{2}{n}\right)^2  + ... + \left(\frac{n}{n}\right)^2 \right]$$

Find the limit of the sequence $\{a_n\}$

my attempt:

We can see $a_n$ like:

$$a_n = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^2 = \frac{(n+1)(2n+1)}{6n^2}$$

therefore we have that:

$$\{a_n\}= \left\{ \frac{(n+1)(2n+1)}{6n^2} \right\}=\left\{\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{6n^2}\right\}$$

therefore

$$\{a_n\} \to \frac{1}{3} $$

Am I right or I have to say it different?, An if I am wrong can you help me to fix it please, thanks.

Comment: It's fine, assuming you can use $\frac{1}{n} \to 0,\, \frac{1}{n^2}\to 0$ and the sum formula for the first $n$ squares without comment. If you can't, you'd need to insert appropriate remarks about these facts.

Comment: I think your work looks correct.

Comment: That's weird notation to distinguish between $\{a_n\}$ and $a_n$. Completely unnecessary in this case. You just have $a_n=...$ and thus $a_n\to \frac 13$.

Comment: then i am wrong ?

Comment: The answer is correct, it's just weird to write $\{a_n\}=\{\dots\}$ and then say $\{a_n\}\to \frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: aaaa ok :) jajajaja well I correct it, but I think both solutions are right isnt? mookid's and mine :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is right. However,
when $f$ is continuous,
$$
\frac 1n\sum_{k=1}^n f\left(\frac kn\right)\to\int_0^1 f(t)dt
$$

Comment: Oh good the f is x^2 isnt :)

Comment: That might help him, if he already knows the integral of $x^2$, but he might be in a chapter about integration and trying to do the necessary work to evaluate $\int_0^1 x^2dx$...

Comment: @ThomasAndrews a reminder is always good.

Comment: Umm, a reminder of what for whom? @mookid

Comment: of common features on integration (from me to OP). It does not seem to be that obvious to him.

Comment: Well we have already know that integral and the facts from my proof :), and can you help me with this question please http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1024736/understanding-and-proving-things-in-a-proof